# Simplify complexity

Tags: javascript, time-complexity

I came across this questions which asks to create a function which will return true/false based on the passed array containing all the letters to make up the passed word. Each letter from array can only be used once.

Here's my attempt:

```
const checkArray = (word, arr) => {
    let good = true
    word.split('').forEach(letter => {
        const letterIdx = arr.findIndex(arrLetter => arrLetter === letter)
        if (letterIdx === -1) good = false

        arr.splice(letterIdx, 1)
    })

    return good
}

const word = 'goal'
const arr1 = ['g', 'o','a','l','x','a','d'] // true
const arr1 = ['g', 'r','a','l','x','a','d'] // false
```

With my approach, a loop inside a loop is used. Whats a better (less complexity) way of solving this issue?

Comment: For help improving working code, please see https://codereview.stackexchange.com. Be sure to read [their help](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting.

Comment: Can `arr` contain repeated letters?